# Hosting Web Application on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, web-hosting

I Have a simple MVC5 Web application with MSSQL2012 database and application details are listed bellow.

- Application size is 50MB.
- SQL Database size will be maximum 500MB.
- The application is accessing only 5 users concurrently.
- Users are working on this application only 12 Hours per day.

I'm thinking of publishing this application on windows azure.But since I'm new to windows azure and I don't know what is the best plan on azure for this application.

And also since this is very low budget project, what is the best hosting provider for this application.(amazon etc..)

Thanks,

Comment: I suggest you read more about Azure. You'll find answers to all your questions on Azure website itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at Azure, sounds like website + database is what you're looking for. You can create this easily on the Azure Portal.

I'd start by looking at this:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/

and this:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/

In terms of price, sounds like free edition website would work for you as shown here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

and you can take a look at a basic edition database which would cost you 5$ a month:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/

Comment: Hi Boboyum, Thank you for the reply.As you mentioned if I use free edition website and basic edition database, does the maximum cost per month is 5$?

Comment: from my understanding, yep.

Comment: if you wanted to give it a try for free, check this out: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0044p/